# select with ngOptions for range

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I want to create a select list with a list of integer with angular 4.

I've made a pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'range'
})
export class RangePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], min: number, max: number): any {
    while (min < max) {
      value.push(min++);
    }
    return value;
  }

}
```

and added to my `app.module.ts` > `declarations`.
I have also added to `imports` the `FormsModule`.

I don't figure out why this doesn't works:

```
<select ngOptions="[] | range:1:55"></select>
```

and this, in the same page, works perfectly:

```
{{[] | range:1:55}}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no ngOptions Directive try  this:

```
 <select>
   <option *ngFor="let opt of [] | range:1:55" [value]="opt ">opt</option> 
 </select>
```

Comment: works. The square brackets on opt are missing `..>{{opt}}</opt..`